# Getting has_object_permission() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'self', 'request', 'view', and 'obj'

Tags: django-rest-framework, permissions, arguments

I am trying to create a has_object_permission function which is in a `permissions.py` file in a custom class:

```
class IsOwnerOrAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("has object permissions statement")
        return obj.owner == request.user

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print("has permissions statement")
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated
```

My view set looks like this:

```
class SchoolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = School.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdmin, 
        IsOwnerOrAdmin.has_object_permission()]
    ...
```

I get the following error when I call the /schools/ endpoint:

```
TypeError: has_object_permission() missing 4 required positional 
arguments: 'self', 'request', 'view', and 'obj'
```

However, has_permissions works fine and I don't have to explicitly call it in my permission_classes array. It just gets called. How do I pass these arguments? Am I doing this correctly? I tried a few variations of passing self, passing SchoolViewSet, passing `obj=queryset` etc. Was not sure if that was correct. Could not find exactly what I needed to fix this on the internets.

**Update**
How do I change the code in order to call has_object_permission just like has_permission gets called automatically?

Answer (score 0):

`permission_classes` is not defined correctly. It should only include the customised class.

```
class SchoolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = School.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdmin]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, has_object_permission won't get called like this. Maybe this viewset can't call has_object_permission?